# Workflow: If item returned equals yes send an email. Im lost

Tags: designer-workflow, workflow-variable, send-email, item-checkedin

I want to send an email when a key is returned. The user who updates the list has a checkbox for yes it was returned. Once that field goes from blank to "Yes" I want an email to be sent to the user who signed out that key.

this is what I have. Every time anybody updates the list after it was created the workflow sends an email that it was returned. The problem is it sends it regardless if you checked that box or not.

Stage Key Returned

```
If Current Item: Created By is a valid SharePoint user

Email Current Item : Crewmember signing out key/radio

End work flow
```

Comment: .  I think you are going  in the right direction.  I have a  few workflow set-up in designer based on a choice column.  If  Column A equals A Email User 1, else if Column A equals B Email User 2.  It looks like you would want it set to email Modified By .

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that there was a checked box that says automatically start workflow when an item was updated . So if someone wanted to swap out a key instead of redoing a whole new list instead we would update the key number but as soon as we save it sends the email that the key was returned. since that option was checked. I still cant figure this our I want it to initiate when If current item: Key returned Equals Yes Then send email. The other problem is I cant add text to the second value.

Answer (score 2):

your workflow should have below steps

`If <checkbox> field is blank
    wait for <checkbox field> to be 'Yes'
    Send Mail
<<end if>>`

This should solve your issue.